# wordpress shortcode for contact form plugin not working

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, plugins, shortcode

I made my first WP plugin, it is a contact form - here is the code:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Example Contact Form Plugin
Plugin URI: http://example.com
Description: Simple non-bloated WordPress Contact Form
Version: 1.0
Author: Agbonghama Collins
Author URI: http://w3guy.com
*/

function html_form_code() {
    echo '<form action="' . esc_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) . '" method="post">';
    echo '<p>';
    echo 'Your Name (required) <br />';
    echo '<input type="text" name="cf-name" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+" value="' . ( isset( $_POST["cf-name"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["cf-name"] ) : '' ) . '" size="40" />';
    echo '</p>';
    echo '<p>';
    echo 'Your Email (required) <br />';
    echo '<input type="email" name="cf-email" value="' . ( isset( $_POST["cf-email"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["cf-email"] ) : '' ) . '" size="40" />';
    echo '</p>';
    echo '<p>';
    echo 'Subject (required) <br />';
    echo '<input type="text" name="cf-subject" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+" value="' . ( isset( $_POST["cf-subject"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["cf-subject"] ) : '' ) . '" size="40" />';
    echo '</p>';
    echo '<p>';
    echo 'Your Message (required) <br />';
    echo '<textarea rows="10" cols="35" name="cf-message">' . ( isset( $_POST["cf-message"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["cf-message"] ) : '' ) . '</textarea>';
    echo '</p>';
    echo '<p><input type="submit" name="cf-submitted" value="Send"/></p>';
    echo '</form>';
}

function deliver_mail() {

    // if the submit button is clicked, send the email
    if ( isset( $_POST['cf-submitted'] ) ) {

        // sanitize form values
        $name    = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["cf-name"] );
        $email   = sanitize_email( $_POST["cf-email"] );
        $subject = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["cf-subject"] );
        $message = esc_textarea( $_POST["cf-message"] );

        // get the blog administrator's email address
        $to = get_option( 'admin_email' );

        $headers = "From: $name <$email>" . "\r\n";

        // If email has been process for sending, display a success message
        if ( wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers ) ) {
            echo '<div>';
            echo '<p>Thanks for contacting me, expect a response soon.</p>';
            echo '</div>';
        } else {
            echo 'An unexpected error occurred';
        }
    }
}

function cf_shortcode() {
    ob_start();
    deliver_mail();
    html_form_code();

    return ob_get_clean();
}

add_shortcode( 'contact_form', 'cf_shortcode' );
?>
```

[This](http://www.sitepoint.com/build-your-own-wordpress-contact-form-plugin-in-5-minutes/) is the tutorial I used to make it.

When I put `[contact_form]` in a post or on a page, nothing appears...no contact form.

Why won't the form appear?

Answer (score 1):

Enable the plugin in the administration panel.

Comment: haha, thank you for the suggestion but that is not the problem, i made sure its enabled...and everytime i make a change to the code i deactivate and reactivate.

Comment: @ewizard I've copied your code and it works fine. Do you test it on a clean and updated wordpress ? I suggest you to try to disable all other plugins you might have, to ensure there is no conflict.

Comment: i tried it with all plugins disabled...i am working with the latest version or wordpress although i am not sure whether or not it is "clean" - i also found a workaround which i will post as an answer...i think it is a fairly common work around for shortcode errors.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `[contact_form]` in the wordpress editor, I used`<?php echo do_shortcode('[contact_form]'); ?>` in the php template for that page.